# hadoop LocalJobRunner not working?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i'am trying to run example from hadoop-definitive guide 3rd edition. in chapter 5 the author demonstrated using LocalJobRunner class which helps to run hadoop jobs from input data found locally and output the result locally. for this author tells to set the configuratin property mapred.job.tracker to "local". I have done this but still the program tried to find the input and output path in hdfs .

My second question is that am not able to find LocalJobRunner class in hadoop 2.3.0 javadocs api?

Answer (score 0):

```
i have managed to find the answer to my first part of the question. the problem was with my configuration.xml file. i was using following values :

<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:8021</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**the actual configuration should be**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>file:///</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>local</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

however i still not have found answer to my second part of question i.e I'am not able to find LocalJobRunner in hadoop 2.3.0 docs. here is the link for docs [hadoop javadocs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/)